# How could I get the access token for Sharepoint from a WebPart?

Tags: azure, iframe, sharepoint, web-parts

I have a website where the users login against Azure AD. I need to embed (as iframe) this website inside a Sharepoint intranet with a WebPart.

How could I get the access token for Sharepoint from a WebPart?.

In the webpart I have something like this:

```
OAUTHOKEN = ¿?
<iframe src="https://myweb.org/oauthCallback.html?token=OAUTHTOKEN" width="250px" height="250px"/>
```

Could you tell me the way to obtain the access token?

Regards!

Comment: Would be interesting to know it you found an answer to this. Pls do share.

Answer (score -1):

Since you are logging in against Azure AD, you should have token after logging in.

You can exchange that token using on behalf of flow to fetch token that can be used for SharePoint. You can get more info on below link on how to use on behalf of flow:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow

You can use below function:

```
public async Task<string> GetSPAccessToken(string access_token)
{
    string token = "", refresh_token = "";
    // This is to replace bearer if access_token is retrieved from HTTP Headers
    access_token = access_token.Replace("bearer ", "").Replace("Bearer ", "");
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
    var keyValuePairs = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
    // Make sure you have give proper API permission to Azure AD app
    // in this case AllSites.Read
    string SPScope = "{SiteUrl}" + "/AllSites.Read";
    keyValuePairs.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("scope", SPScope));
    keyValuePairs.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", Client_id));
    keyValuePairs.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", Client_secret));
    keyValuePairs.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer"));
    keyValuePairs.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("requested_token_use",  "on_behalf_of"));
    keyValuePairs.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("assertion", access_token));
    var client1 = new HttpClient();
    var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{YOURDOMAIN}/oauth2/v2.0/token") { Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(keyValuePairs) };

    using (var res = client1.SendAsync(req).Result)
    {
        if (res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var jsonresult = JObject.Parse(await res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
            token = (string)jsonresult["access_token"];
            refresh_token = (string)jsonresult["refresh_token"];

        }
    }

    return token;
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Sushrut. Thanks for your response.

Could you give me the context to use this function?. How can I obtain the param: access_token?

Regards

Comment: I re-read you question and I think my above code is other way around to get SharePoint access token from App access token. To get SharePoint access token you can try: https://www.advaiya.com/blog/access-sharepoint-rest-api-using-oauth/ and then using that SharePoint access token you use on behalf of flow to get access token to the Azure AD app. Sorry if I am confusing.